# Angular changing style on scroll in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have set up changing of the background for a back arrow on my page. It works fine when I scroll down and then it changes the background as it should, but it is not working after I scroll back to the top, it is not changing back to transparent background. After testing on simulator and real device I have found out that it is only working in browser and not on any other platform.

This is my view:

```
<div class="back-arrow" style="background-color: {{ background }};">
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left" ui-sref="main.front">
    </a>
</div>

<ion-content on-scroll="changeArrowBackground()">
    ...code...
</ion-content>
```

And this is my controller:

```
$scope.changeArrowBackground = function(){
    console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top == 0);
    if ($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top == 0) {
      console.log('transparent');
      $scope.background = "transparent";
    }
    else {
      console.log('not-transparent');
      $scope.background = "#353A41";
    }
}
```

Whenever I scroll it logs correctly based on the position.

Comment: How are you calling `changeArrowBackground`?

Comment: I have edited the question with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be triggering an angular cycle. Try forcing it with `$scope.$apply()`.

```
$scope.changeArrowBackground = function(){
    if ($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top == 0) {
      $scope.background = "transparent";
    } else {
      $scope.background = "#353A41";
    }
    $scope.$apply();
}
```